# Django collectstatic error: No such file or directory: '/app/appName/static'

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, static

I've been getting this *collectstatic* error when I run the following in command line:

```
C:\Users\Steven\site1>heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
Running python manage.py collectstatic on my-compository... up, run.9943 (Free)

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /app/mynotes/staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 193, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 115, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 399, in listdir
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/mynotes/static'
```

I haven't been able to figure out what was wrong after much searching.
Here's a slight preview of my directory structure:

```
-site1
 - mynotes
      - settings.py
      - staticfiles (empty)
      - wsgi.py
      - urls.py
 - mynotess
      - static
          - mynotess
             - capture1.jpg
             - carousel.css
             - capture2.jpg
      - templates
      - views.py
      - other files related to the app
 - users
      - files related to this app, no static files here
 - manage.py
 - .gitignore
 - requirements.txt
 - Procfile
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'mynotess',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mynotes.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mynotes/templates')], #originally empty
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mynotes.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_URL = 'users/login'

BOOTSTRAP3 = {'include_jquery': True}

if os.getcwd() == '/app':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

I don't understand why it's giving this error. It doesn't work with just `python manage.py collectstatic` either, which gives me an error as follows: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.` I've specified the path to the static root *mynotes/static* and it has been set up to collect all the static files there. I don't understand why it's telling me that no such directory exists. Another thing that confuses me too is the line:

`/app/mynotes/staticfiles/`

I don't have a directory called *staticfiles* so I'm not sure how this got here. I typed *static* in my STATIC_ROOT so I'm not sure why it comes out as *staticfiles*. Is this something to worry about or is this some default thing? Could it be because I changed the code from the last time I deployed it (which was when `DEBUG=True`) but it hasn't updated? I tried making an empty directory called *staticfiles*, but it still gives me the same error.

I'm kind of new to Django and any kind of help is greatly appreciated! P.S. I have thoroughly read the docs but I did not get anything useful out of it.

**EDIT**
I got *heroku run python manage.py collectstatic* to work. I figured out why *staticfiles* was there (just had to re-deploy it). But, my JPG/PNG images and CSS are still not appearing in my website after deployment. This is specifically only when `DEBUG = False` (it works when `True`). Plus, *python manage.py collectstatic* still gives the same error, though I'm not sure if it matters?

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'', include('mynotess.urls', namespace= "mynotess")), #telling it to look into the urls.py in mynotess for more URLS!
]

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

Comment: On which level is `manage.py`?

Comment: I just edited the post to include manage.py

Comment: Yup cheers. Well I don't see `static` directory on the level with manage.py. Also I'd recommend you change `STATIC_ROOT` variable dir to `static_root` so that it's not just `static`. Where does `.../staticfiles/` come from, seriously no idea.

Comment: okay I just did that, but the static files (images, css) are still not appearing after I deploy it (specifically, when DEBUG = False). When I ran heroku run python manage.py collectstatic, at the end it says "74 static files copied to '/app/mynotes/static_root'." just wondering if this is right since I don't have a directory inside mynotes called 'static_root'? Also, it still gives me the same error when I type in python manage.py collectstatic only?

Comment: Ok, there's some magic going on there. To be honest it's hard to guess without direct access. Also probably the reason I don't use Heroku.

Comment: I suspect that the error you get when you run `python manage.py collect static` (locally, I assume) is because `STATIC_ROOT` is only set on Heroku (it's indented under the `if os.getcwd()...` guard)